# ID value is not continuous in django admin interface

Tags: django

When I delete an existing record from database and recreated a exactly same record through Django admin interface, the id value shows in Django admin interface is not continuous. For instance, the record with id value is 6 and the previous one is 5, then I delete the one with id 6. When I recreate it, the id value becomes 7 instead of 6. I think it supposes to be 6. It this a error and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: No, it's not an error. Primary keys are unique for each entity and are not re-used just because you delete one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct behaviour. Primary keys should not get re-used, especially to avoid conflicts when it has been referenced in other tables.

See this SO question for more info about it: [How to restore a continuous sequence of IDs as primary keys in a SQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13146441/1431750)

If you really want to [reset the Auto Increment of PK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923132/1431750), you can do `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` (for MySQL). Other DBs may have different limitations like not being able to reset to any value lower than the highest used, even if there are gaps (MySQL:InnoDB).